# Filtering XML attributes

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, filtering

I have this script below which filters out a list of xmls based on the attribute `value`:

```
gci $path | Select-Xml -XPATH "//Order[contains(@Value, '0')]"
```

I am trying to filter out those XMLs with a "value of zero". The problem is that when I run the script against my source, it returns everything that has a "0" in the value. How can I change the filter to only filter on "0", ie. no value greater than zero? I guess there is a filter to replace "contains" to something like "match", but I've tried this. Can't find any alternatives on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Where-Object` filter with a `-not` condition to exclude all files where your XPath expression produces a match:

```
Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {
  -not (Select-Xml -Path $_.FullName -XPath "//Order[contains(@value, '0')]")
}
```

Note that this might produce false negatives, though (e.g. if the attribute `value` contains a value like 10, 201, …). If you only want to exclude files where an attribute `value` is exactly 0 you can do so with a numeric comparison:

```
Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {
  -not (Select-Xml -Path $_.FullName -XPath "//Order[@value = 0]"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. I have found an alternative way of doing this now: $All1 = gci $path | Select-Xml -XPATH //Order | Select-Object -ExpandProperty node 
$Filtered = $All | Where {$_.Lines -eq "0"}